# IAR STM8 delay function

Tags: iar, stm8

How do I write a delay function in the STM8 - IAR Embedded Workbench?
I used the search-function inside the IDE, so I found the `__delay()` function but if I try to use it I get:

> "no definition for '__delay'"

Comment: Are you including the header that declares that function?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply,
i don't think so, according to the help it is a "pre-defined system macro"

Comment: I'm not familiar with IAR Embedded Workbench, so I'm just guessing. Can you see what file the "delay" is declared and try to include that in your source file. You might have to google: "include file for IAR Embedded Workbench".

Comment: According to the Help-function i have to define my system macros in an extra file which will be loaded while the code is executing. Is there seriously no build-in delay-function?

Answer (score 2):

IAR has __delay_cycles you can use it.
Here a basic code

```
#include <intrinsics.h>
#if !defined(F_CPU)
#warning no F_CPU
#endif

#define delay_us(us) __delay_cycles((F_CPU  *(us)/4000000uL)
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually STM has a demo regarding how to use STM8's TIM4 to create a delay function. You can find it in STM8 Peripheral Libs provided by STM

Comment: Can you expand this answer?